# How to write a VB script to find multiple strings within all cells and highlight each row?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change the following lines of code to find string within the worksheet and highlight the rows if the string is contained in the cell?  For example, search string is "SV-32346r1" and the cell content is "The document contains a listing of cars with the identifier SV-32346r1 in Cali".  this row should be highlighted.  The code below only search for exact matches.

```
If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then       'InStr returns 0 if the string isn't found
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Highlights the row in red if value found
End If
```

Full Code here (thanks Aiken):

```
Public Sub HighlightListedValues()
Dim strConcatList As String
Dim cell As Range

'Creates a string concatenating your list of strings, separated by |s
'e.g. "item1|item2|item3|item4|"
For Each cell In Sheets("List").Range("A1:A40")
strConcatList = strConcatList & cell.Value & "|"
Next cell

'For each used cell in Column A of sheet1, check whether the value in that cell
'is contained within the concatenated string
For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("Gap Analysis").Range("E:E"), Sheets("Gap Analysis").UsedRange)
If InStr(strConcatList, cell.Value) > 0 Then       'InStr returns 0 if the string isn't found
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Highlights the row in red if value found
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in a non-VBA solution, here's how to do it with conditional formatting. Assuming your data is in column A and your list of codes is in C2:C7, you can use this conditional formatting formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF($A4,"*" & $C$2:$C$7 & "*"))
```

Set it up like this:

[image]

Note that this allows you to use multiple codes, which I'm guessing might be why you are using VBA.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  And this is a better option since some environments do not permit macros.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing each cell against the list, you need to test each element in the list against the cell.  One way is by using regular expressions.  It turns out that a pipe delimited list in a regular expression performs that kind of matching.  In the code below, change "Sheet1" to "List"; and "Sheet2" to "Gap Analysis".  Note that I changed how StrConcat is put together so there is no pipe at the beginning or end of the list, and also so that there are no "empty" items.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub HighlightListedValues()
Dim strConcatList As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim RE As Object

'Creates a string concatenating your list of strings, separated by |s
'e.g. "item1|item2|item3|item4|"
For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A40")
    If cell.Value <> "" Then strConcatList = strConcatList & "|" & cell.Value
Next cell
strConcatList = Mid(strConcatList, 2)

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = strConcatList
End With

'For each used cell in Column A of sheet1, check whether the value in that cell
'is contained within the concatenated string
For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("sheet2").Range("E:E"), Sheets("sheet2").UsedRange)
If RE.test(cell.Value) = True Then
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Highlights the row in red if value found
Else
    cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

And if you didn't want to bother with Regular Expressions, here's a way to do it with "native" VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub HighlightListedValues()
Dim strConcatList() As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim I As Long

'Creates an arrary of your list of strings
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A40")
    ReDim strConcatList(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Value))
    For Each cell In .Cells
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            I = I + 1
            strConcatList(I) = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End With

'For each used cell in Column A of sheet1, check whether the value in that cell
'is contained within the concatenated string
For Each cell In Intersect(Sheets("sheet2").Range("E:E"), Sheets("sheet2").UsedRange)
    For I = 1 To UBound(strConcatList)
        With cell.EntireRow.Interior
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, strConcatList(I), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            .Color = vbRed
            Exit For
        Else
            .Color = xlNone
        End If
        End With
    Next I
Next cell
End Sub
```